# Vertically align in an absolute div?

Tags: css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emszzgcs/)

I've checked many SO posts, looked at various vertical align tricks (-50%, table-cell etc) but I still cant figure this one out.

```
<div class="main">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Information_icon.svg"/>
    <div class="text"><span class="inner-text">this is some text</span></div>
</div>
```

I need to have the image and text div absolutely positioned and offset slightly top and bottom.

I can position the image fine, but aligning the text presents an issue. How can I vertically and horizontally align the text?

No flex please.

Comment: [text-align: center;](https://jsfiddle.net/emszzgcs/4/)

Comment: so text-align center now vertically aligns?

Comment: Lovely attitude, have fun figuring it out :D

Comment: I don't see any attempts here to vertically center your elements.

Comment: The image is vertically aligned but not the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, @Raznyy answered what you asked with it being offset. If you want them to be vertically aligned in the middle then you could do it this way.

https://jsfiddle.net/emszzgcs/6/

I added another div for the content and made them act like a table.

```
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;
    display: table;
}

.main-content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like in this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emszzgcs/5/).

Text is vertically aligned as you want;
You just need to give `<div class='text'>` - `width:100%` and `text-align:center`;
Hope it helps!

here's sample code :

```
.text{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto
     /* */
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

** EDIT **

[Here's is new code.](https://jsfiddle.net/emszzgcs/8/)
I set `height` for example to 20px so if you want it to be vertically align you just need to set `top:50%` and `margin-top: -10px` becouse it is a half of element height.
Sorry for my mistake.
`

Comment: Thanks but this text is not vertically aligned. It just has top position of 150px;

Comment: @panthro - You said it needs to be offset in your question so this does answer what you are asking. It can't be vertically aligned in the middle and offset.